# Secuirty Token Escrow setllement

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design, tokens

Is Esrcow could be applied in ST 20 tokens ?
If yes, please guide for the same.

Comment: yes, Escrow settlement to St 20 is similar to ERC-20. I find no substantial up-gradation to ST 20 apart from KYA/AML implementation.